# set amount of blocks to show using html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that shows and hides blocks on click.

How can I alter this by setting the amount of blocks to show via HTML using data attribute

for example

```
<div class="one cards"data-desktop=4>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="random_cms-class">
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <a class="show_more_link" href="#">Show more</a>
  <a class="show_less_link" href="#">Show less</a>
</div>
```

...
    
    
      ...
    
    
      ...
    
    
      ...
    
    
      ...
    
    
      ...
    
    
      Show more
      Show less

the first I would like to show 4 div's the second i would like to show 2.
So far my jquery will only show `.slice(3)` how can I change this to reflect the `data-desktop=4`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  cards = $('.cards');
  $.each(cards, function(key,value) {
    $(this)
      .find('.random_cms-class')
      .slice(5)
      .hide(); 
  });
});

$('.show_more_link').click(function() {
  // show all the cards
  // show the "less" link and hide the "more" link
  $(this).parent().parent().find(":hidden").show();
  $(this).siblings().show();
  $(this).hide();
});
$('.show_less_link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent()
    .find('.random_cms-class')
    .slice(3)
    .hide(); 
  $(this).siblings().show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.random_cms-class {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.show_less_link {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one cards">
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <a class="show_more_link" href="#">Show more</a>
      <a class="show_less_link" href="#">Show less</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="two cards">
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <a class="show_more_link" href="#">Show more</a>
      <a class="show_less_link" href="#">Show less</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just to clarify, If there are 8 blocks and the data-desktop=4 then on page load I wish to show 4, and on click show more show all 8, then on click hide show 4 again.

Comment: For clarification, if a cards block has 8 children, and the data-desktop is 2, how should that work with repeated clicks of show more and show less?

Comment: You can try to put your data-desktop in a var/let and show/hide based on the number in your var/let, and you can update your data-desktop also if you have it inside a var, just make a function that gets your var and updates it with whatever you wish

Comment: @Taplar good question. so if the block has 8 children and the data set is 2 the on page load 2 should be shown and if click show more it'll show all 8. on hide then show 2 again

Comment: @RamondeVries good idea ill try this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set initial slice to `$(this).data("desktop")` instead of `3` static. And on showless button click you can set slice to `$(this).parents(".cards").data("desktop")`..

I am reading the data value on setting it initially as well as on hide.

Check snippet below :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  cards = $('.cards');
  $.each(cards, function(key,value) {
    $(this)
      .find('.random_cms-class')
      .slice($(this).data("desktop"))
      .hide(); 
  });
});

$('.show_more_link').click(function() {
  // show all the cards
  // show the "less" link and hide the "more" link
  $(this).parent().parent().find(":hidden").show();
  $(this).siblings().show();
  $(this).hide();
});
$('.show_less_link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent()
    .find('.random_cms-class')
    .slice($(this).parents(".cards").data("desktop"))
    .hide(); 
  $(this).siblings().show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.random_cms-class {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.show_less_link {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}
body{
height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one cards" data-desktop="4">
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <a class="show_more_link" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
      <a class="show_less_link" href="javascript:void(0)">Show less</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="two cards" data-desktop="2">
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="random_cms-class">
      <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <a class="show_more_link" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
      <a class="show_less_link" href="javascript:void(0)">Show less</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update 1:**

Pretty simple, to stop page go on top on click, change href to `javascript:void(0)` instead of `#`.

Comment: Excellent ill implement this and accept your answer thanks

Comment: Seems to work but jumps to the top of my page, as son as i fix this ill accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this uses your `data-desktop` idea to determine the number of elements to show at the page load.  It defines the show more and show less click handlers to show hide the number you want.  The show less is also triggered on page load so it hides the extras so they are not visible at the start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show_more_link').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.cards').find('.random_cms-class').show();
    $(this).closest('.cards').find('.show_less_link').show();
  });

  $('.show_less_link').click(function() {
    var $card = $(this).closest('.cards');

    $card.find('.random_cms-class').slice($card.data('desktop')).hide();
    $card.find('.show_less_link').hide();
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.random_cms-class {
  display: inline-block;
}

.show_less_link {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one cards" data-desktop="2">
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <a class="show_more_link" href="#">Show more</a>
    <a class="show_less_link" href="#">Show less</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="two cards" data-desktop="3">
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <a class="show_more_link" href="#">Show more</a>
    <a class="show_less_link" href="#">Show less</a>
  </div>
</div>
```